# Which ports mean what in my docker application?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to docker and writing a simple node application. I am confused by the various locations that ports are specified:

- The node application listens on a certain port
- The dockerfile defines a port to "expose" the application on
- The docker run command specifies a local machine port, and a container port

**My questions are: Which location is specifying what? Do they all need to be the same?**

**Related files:**

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send("g'day mate");
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("listening")
})
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /

#Copy app sourcecode
COPY . . 

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

#Expose on port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# This is the command to run the app
CMD [ "node", "index.js"]
```

The docker run command

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 test-app
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: The `EXPOSE` in the containerfile defines what port is exposed within the docker-internal network. the `docker run -p 3000:3000` exposes the docker-internal port to the host machine (i.e. `localhost`).

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you for your response. Do you mean then that if I were to write `EXPOSE 3001`, I would also have to change the terminal command to `docker run 3000:3001 test-app` ?

Comment: Exactly. And if you change the `docker run ...` to `docker run -p 3001:3000` (without changing the containerfile), you'd have to reconfigure the client to connect to `localhost:3001`.

Comment: Expose doesn't actually do anything much. It's of informational nature. Some tools will use it, in some scenarios. What is really important is that the port your code is listening on with `app.listen` is the same as the right side of the publish flag. `-p 5000:3000`. The left side can be what you want to map it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The node application listens on a certain port

This port number is very important.  Connections between containers use only this port number and ignore any other settings.  You cannot change this port number with pure Docker settings; it's possible the application supports changing this through a command-line parameter or an environment variable but that will be application-specific.

> The docker run command specifies a local machine port, and a container port

The container port *must* match the application port.  The local machine port can be anything you want provided it's not used by anything else on the host.  These do not need to match.

> The dockerfile defines a port to "expose" the application on

This should be the same as the application port, but it does almost nothing and there are no consequences to getting it wrong or omitting it entirely.

Since "expose" doesn't do anything, this makes the mechanic very simple.  `docker run -p 12345:3000` forwards from port 12345 on the host to port 3000 in the container.  That needs to match where the application is actually listening (it also needs to be listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address and not 127.0.0.1 "only accept connections initiated from within the same container").  Dockerfile `EXPOSE` is pretty much only documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I'm not sure if the concept of port is ok for you.

My teacher use to simplify IP address and port as : IP address is the building and port is the flat in that building you are looking for.

In `index.js` your express application is listening to the flat `3000` of the building it is running in.

Because you are running your app in Docker, then the building is Docker. So the `EXPOSE 3000` in `Dockerfile` is telling to Docker that this port should be exposed (basically not auto closed).

Then in your command `docker run -p 3000:3000` you are telling your host machine (your computer) to link his port 3000 to the port 3000 of Docker.

You can also think it as extension cable : you are wiring the first cable (your computer) to the second one (docker) and then the second one to the third one (express app).